# cljs-http.client get request incompatibility with target

Tags: http, clojure

I'm trying to make an clj-http.client request to a third-party webpage, but am getting the following error response:

```
clj-http: status 403
   {:cached nil,
    :request-time 141,
    :repeatable? false,
    :protocol-version {:name "HTTP", :major 1, :minor 1},
    :streaming? true,
    :http-client
    #object[org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient 0x7d5d53f8 "org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@7d5d53f8"],
    :chunked? true,
    :type :clj-http.client/unexceptional-status,
    :reason-phrase "Forbidden",
    :headers
    {"Server" "cloudflare",
     "Content-Type" "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
     "X-Frame-Options" "SAMEORIGIN",
     "Connection" "close",
     "cf-request-id" "02afa1c33a00000cb192b11200000001",
     "Transfer-Encoding" "chunked",
     "Set-Cookie"
     "__cfduid=d5186984dc436aac8989538666ddb21761589373348; expires=Fri, 12-Jun-20 12:35:48 GMT; path=/; domain=.angel.co; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax",
     "Expect-CT"
     "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
     "CF-RAY" "592c6be52bb00cb1-EWR",
     "Date" "Wed, 13 May 2020 12:35:48 GMT",
     "Vary" "Accept-Encoding",
     "Cache-Control" "no-cache",
     "CF-Chl-Bypass" "1"},
    :orig-content-encoding nil,
    :status 403,
    :length -1,
    :body
    "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class=\"no-js ie6 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class=\"no-js ie7 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class=\"no-js ie8 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=\"no-js\" lang=\"en-US\"> <!--<![endif]-->\n<head>\n<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>\n<meta name=\"captcha-bypass\" id=\"captcha-bypass\" />\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\" />\n<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex, nofollow\" />\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\" />\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"cf_styles-css\" href=\"/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen,projection\" />\n<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel=\"stylesheet\" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href=\"/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen,projection\" /><![endif]-->\n<style type=\"text/css\">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>\n\n\n<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js\"></script><!--<![endif]-->\n<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js\"></script><!--<![endif]-->\n\n\n\n\n</head>\n<body>\n  <div id=\"cf-wrapper\">\n    <div class=\"cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error\" id=\"cookie-alert\" data-translate=\"enable_cookies\">Please enable cookies.</div>\n    <div id=\"cf-error-details\" class=\"cf-error-details-wrapper\">\n      <div class=\"cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview\">\n        <h1 data-translate=\"challenge_headline\">One more step</h1>\n        <h2 class=\"cf-subheadline\"><span data-translate=\"complete_sec_check\">Please complete the security check to access</span> angel.co</h2>\n      </div><!-- /.header -->\n      \n      <div class=\"cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container\">\n        <div class=\"cf-wrapper\">\n          <div class=\"cf-columns two\">\n            <div class=\"cf-column\">\n            \n              <div class=\"cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked\">\n                <form class=\"challenge-form\" id=\"challenge-form\" action=\"/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=0d94e2e21d2ef06ef34bd2b5b4667f279b690108-1589373348-0-ATT4PiY_pQI1dGVw0_sZDV32_7x4mqtO4RepyD-L4i6zBJiIuml25fVlyJaK8uXNJw5ZWnzGlb6y0jGJJ8HIdEz14sOXRUoHqs_naHtwFEQywa8qZf_rwHsBxIUD5y_FNPph6TDrcfLVnQaN9eyy5VjiznzH4y0yeK8cidNnd-qNGw4OIZbFLfv8299DGhvNnBgsbn3BiQ9bkoGOtE4wANUh5U2LTJVAWhlquAvfhjCu6jHlYRXtN5GdnNvfBbCYwWGwCX0j88J-qCjJFOrSvx1_xraYtpB_Y8PpLHZTob_t8POfE0kJpn9ZYxwjhLQhqAAcIoE8fRe7Lv_50pzummklgMLgTRT2_NJGiE-_jNEogQmoTCvGOOmhNCe28SVYkXop9Ajm-z-6xwgoKQnY7EwekXJZCs-4nwpWJ9Gh3HBgVxZRiuv_wKgcmU0sPlLXSL5G8yOVdbBKBtHhQyqadtmTSg_IC2HV7SiYqPoJMmpJGfxxUm1au7ZS9ZiLpokjI5pQDZLpT2ZG-6jVfnTKvt9w_qmMtUSBhDleXd8mG59r\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\">\n  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"r\" value=\"bfe8db4864c274e3ed80528a0e0ad233279c00b9-1589373348-0-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\">\n  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cf_captcha_kind\" value=\"h\">\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/cdn-cgi/scripts/hcaptcha.challenge.js\" data-type=\"normal\"  data-ray=\"592c6be52bb00cb1\" async data-sitekey=\"33f96e6a-38cd-421b-bb68-7806e1764460\"></script>\n  <noscript id=\"cf-captcha-bookmark\" class=\"cf-captcha-info\">\n  <h1 data-translate=\"turn_on_js\" style=\"color:#bd2426;\">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>\n  </noscript>\n  <div id=\"trk_captcha_js\" style=\"background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/nojs/h/transparent.gif?ray=592c6be52bb00cb1')\"></div>\n</form>\n\n              </div>\n            </div>\n\n            <div class=\"cf-column\">\n              <div class=\"cf-screenshot-container\">\n              \n                <span class=\"cf-no-screenshot\"></span>\n              \n              </div>\n            </div>\n          </div><!-- /.columns -->\n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->\n\n      <div class=\"cf-section cf-wrapper\">\n        <div class=\"cf-columns two\">\n          <div class=\"cf-column\">\n            <h2 data-translate=\"why_captcha_headline\">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>\n            \n            <p data-translate=\"why_captcha_detail\">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>\n          </div>\n\n          <div class=\"cf-column\">\n            <h2 data-translate=\"resolve_captcha_headline\">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>\n            \n\n            <p data-translate=\"resolve_captcha_antivirus\">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>\n\n            <p data-translate=\"resolve_captcha_network\">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>\n            \n              \n            \n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.section -->\n      \n\n      <div class=\"cf-error-footer cf-wrapper\">\n  <p>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item\">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>592c6be52bb00cb1</strong></span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-separator\">&bull;</span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item\"><span>Your IP</span>: 128.151.150.1</span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-separator\">&bull;</span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item\"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href=\"https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer\" id=\"brand_link\" target=\"_blank\">Cloudflare</a></span>\n    \n  </p>\n</div><!-- /.error-footer -->\n\n\n    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->\n  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->\n\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  window._cf_translation = {};\n  \n  \n</script>\n\n\n</body>\n</html>\n",
    :trace-redirects []}
```

Where the response says "no-js ie 6 oldie". How do I fix this?

-- EDIT --

Tried this, but it didn't work either

```
curl 'https://angel.co' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=d3d3c3a784a6878d27e67563734baeb7e1589375442; _ga=GA1.2.1171200054.1589375443; _gid=GA1.2.1332292087.1589375443; ajs_user_id=null; ajs_group_id=null; ajs_anonymous_id=%226898badd-9a9e-4876-9a75-e92df55c5d4b%22; _hjid=58408190-990c-4a5b-86c8-ac6003d5fe93' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
```

Comment: The status code says 403 and the HTML there says alot more (basically:
log in). The request you are sending (and failed to add to the
question), does something the other side does not allow.  Most likely
you are not sending a token or some other mean of auth and also don't
communicate that you are interested in JSON or such.

Comment: the request I'm sending is (http/get "h t t p s://angel.co").

Comment: If you want to scrape the page, try changing the user-agent

Comment: curl 'https://angel.co/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=d3d3c3a784a6878d27e67563734baeb7e1589375442; _ga=GA1.2.1171200054.1589375443; _gid=GA1.2.1332292087.1589375443; ajs_user_id=null; ajs_group_id=null; ajs_anonymous_id=%226898badd-9a9e-4876-9a75-e92df55c5d4b%22; _hjid=58408190-990c-4a5b-86c8-ac6003d5fe93' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'

Comment: ^ doesn't work. Basically copied as curl from Firefox network tab.

Comment: If you have new insigts please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61774924/edit) the question

Comment: You have to bypass Cloudflare's anti scrape protection